# Collection Boolean isn't being set to false - Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, meteor

So in short, the app that i'm developing is a bus timetable app using Meteor, as a practice project.

inside my body.js, I have an interval that runs every second, to fetch the current time and compare to items in a collection.

To show relevant times, I have added an isActive boolean, whenever the current time = sartTime of the collection, it sets it to true, and that is working fine. 
But when I do the same thing for endTime and try to set it to false, so I can hide that timeslot, it just doesn't work. Even consoles don't show up. What am I missing? I have recently just started doing meteor, so excuse the redundancies.
Worth noting that the times that I'm comparing to are times imported from an CSV file, so they have to be in the 00:00 AM/PM format.

Thank you guys so much for your time.

Body.js code:

```
Template.Body.onCreated(function appBodyOnCreated() {
    Meteor.setInterval(() => {
      var h = (new Date()).getHours();      
      const m = ((new Date()).getMinutes() <10?'0':'') + ((new Date()).getMinutes());    
      var ampm = h >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM';
      ampmReac.set(ampm);

      if (h > 12) {
          h -= 12;
      } else if (h === 0) {
         h = 12;
      }
      const timeAsAString = `${h}${m}`;
      const timeAsAStringFormat = `${h}:${m}`; 
      whatTimeIsItString.set(timeAsAStringFormat + ampm);                // convert to a string
      const timeAsANumber = parseInt(timeAsAString);    // convert to a number
      whatTimeIsIt.set(timeAsANumber);                  // update our reactive variable


        if (Timetables.findOne({TimeStart: whatTimeIsItString.get()}).TimeStart == whatTimeIsItString.get())
        {
        var nowTimetable = Timetables.findOne({TimeStart: whatTimeIsItString.get() });
          Timetables.update({_id : nowTimetable._id },{$set:{isActive : true}});
          console.log('I am inside the START statement');


        }  

        else if (Timetables.findOne({TimeEnd: whatTimeIsItString.get()}).TimeEnd == whatTimeIsItString.get())
        {
        var nowTimetable = Timetables.findOne({TimeEnd: whatTimeIsItString.get() });
          Timetables.update({_id : nowTimetable._id },{$set:{isActive : false}});
          console.log('I am inside the END statement');


        }  


    }, 1000);  //reactivate this function every second
 });
})
```

Comment: Working with times as strings is just a nightmare. I recommend you convert your time strings to actual times (in UTC) and store them that way then work in actual times. Your code will be so much simpler.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do so? If i got this right: extract time from DB, put it in a var, convert the var to UTC date and then do operations from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it to work eventually. My problem was that it was never going to the second `IF` statement.
What I have done is set up a whole new Meteor.interval(() >) function, and placed that second `IF` in there, as is.

I think the problem was that it was it checks the first `IF` statement and gets stuck there, no matter what the outcome of the parameters is.

Answer (score 0):

Very probably it is just that your `if` / `else` blocks does what you ask it:

1. It tries to find a document in `Timetables`, with specified `TimeStart`. If so, it makes this document as "active".
2. If **no document is previously found**, i.e. there is *no timeslot* which `TimeStart` is equal to current time, then it tries to find a document with specified `TimeEnd`.

But your `else if` block is executed *only* if the previous `if` block does not find anything.

Therefore if you have a next timeslot which starts when your current timeslot ends, your `if` block gets executed for that next timeslot, but the `else if` block is never executed to de-activate your current timeslot.

An easy solution would be to transform your `else if` block in an independent `if` block, so that it is tested whether the previous one (i.e. TimeStart) finds something or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the first thing I tried. Still did not work. I noticed that it is not reading "TimeEnd". I tried to console.log the TimeEnd, and it is not getting it. I think the problem is in the format; it is just not finding it.

Comment: If you do not describe what you have tried in your question, we will not be able to provide relevant help.

Comment: I managed to fix it eventually, as explained in my comment below. Thank you for your patience with me, coding is not my best suit, but I'm working on it :)

Comment: No problem I am glad you managed to find a solution on your own! Nice to also share your solution here in case other people face a similar situation. Keep up the good work!